# Why my android GridView appear different from normal. It's covered by a holo blue block

Tags: android, gridview

Why my android GridView appear different from normal. It's covered by a holo blue block.

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/devicesScreen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/defaultPaddingSmall" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblNoGatewayDevices"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/tabDetailContainerTopPadding"
        android:textSize="@dimen/infoMsgTextSize"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <!-- <ca.laplanete.mobile.pageddragdropgrid.PagedDragDropGrid -->
    <!-- xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" -->
    <!-- android:id="@+id/gridGatewayDevices" -->
    <!-- android:layout_width="fill_parent" -->
    <!-- android:layout_height="0dip" -->
    <!-- android:layout_weight="1" -->
    <!-- android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" -->
    <!-- android:columnWidth="@dimen/grid_column_width" -->
    <!-- android:gravity="center" -->
    <!-- android:horizontalSpacing="5dp" -->
    <!-- android:numColumns="4" -->
    <!-- android:scrollbars="none" -->
    <!-- android:stretchMode="columnWidth" -->
    <!-- android:verticalSpacing="5dp" /> -->

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridGatewayDevices"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:columnWidth="@dimen/grid_column_width"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I don't want the blue color covering my GridView just like below.
http://www.sofatrip.cn/WeChat_1435115165.jpeg

Can anyone please tell me what's going on?

I would appreciate it.

Comment: Finally I solved this by setting a background. It sucks. Why is the default background is blue? does anyone has an idea?